# Convert String With Comma To Number Using Python Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe, types

I am generating a pivot table report using the pandas Python module. The source data includes a lot of readings measured in milliseconds. If the number of milliseconds exceeds 999 then the value in that CSV file will include commas (e.g. 1,234 = 1.234 seconds).

Here's how I'm trying to run the report:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pool_usage = pd.read_csv("c:/foo/ds-dump.csv")

# Add a column to the end that shows you where the data came from
pool_usage["Source File"] = "ds-dump.csv"

report = pool_usage.pivot_table(values=['Average Pool Size', 'Average Usage Time (ms)'], index=['Source File'], aggfunc=np.max)

print(report)
```

The problem is that the dtype for the **Average Usage Time (ms)** is an object so the `np.max` function just treats it like it's NaN. I therefore never see any values greater than 999.

I tried fixing the issue like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pool_usage = pd.read_csv("c:/foo/ds-dump.csv")

# Add a column to the end that shows you where the data came from
pool_usage["Source File"] = "ds-dump.csv"

# Convert strings to numbers if possible
pool_usage = pool_usage.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)

report = pool_usage.pivot_table(values=['Average Pool Size', 'Average Usage Time (ms)'], index=['Source File'], aggfunc=np.max)

print(report)
```

This did actually change the dtype of the **Average Usage Time** column to a float but all of the values that are greater than 999 are still treated like NaN's.

How can I convert the **Average Usage Time** column to a float even though it's possible that some of the values may include commas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `read_csv` function takes an optional `thousands` argument. Its default is `None` so you can change it to `","` to have it recognise `1,234` as `1234` when it reads the file:

```
pd.read_csv("c:/foo/ds-dump.csv", thousands=",")
```

The column holding the millisecond values should then have the `int64` datatype once the file has been read into memory.